# How do I execute something after $.each finishes iterating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, es6-promise

So basically I have this very simple counter that loads JSON files from 5 different locations and counts the number of entries:

```js
let count = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    total: 0
};

let url = {
    1: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    2: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
    3: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    4: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
    5: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
};

function fetchJSONList(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => { return response.json(); })
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
    });
}

function checkAll() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.each(url, function(key) {
            fetchJSONList(url[key])
                .then(list => {
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
                        const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                        $(spanID).text(0);
                    }
                    $.each(list, function() {
                        count[key]++;
                        count.total++;

                        const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                        $(spanID).text(count[key]);
                    });
                })
                .catch(reject);
        });
        resolve();
    });
}

checkAll()
    .then($("#count-total").text(count.total))
    .catch(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="site-list">
        <li><span>API 1: </span><span id="api-1">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 2: </span><span id="api-2">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 3: </span><span id="api-3">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 4: </span><span id="api-4">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 5: </span><span id="api-5">Loading...</span></li>
</ul>
    
<span>Total: </span><span id="count-total">Loading...</span>
```

As you can see, now the total amount is updated to "0" immediately after the scripts loads (i.e. the promise returned by function `checkAll()` is resolved immediately). However, I would like the total value to update only after `$.each` has finished iterating through the `url` variable.

Any ideas how to do that?

---

**Edit:** So considering T.J. Crowder's answer,

```js
let count = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    total: 0
};

let url = {
    1: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    2: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
    3: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    4: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
    5: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
};

function fetchJSONList(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => { return response.json(); })
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
    });
}

Promise
.all(
    Object.entries(url).map(([key, value]) => {
        fetchJSONList(value)
            .then(list => {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(0);
                }
                $.each(list, function() {
                    count[key]++;
                    count.total++;

                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(count[key]);
                });
            })
    })
)
.then($("#count-total").text(count.total))
.catch(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="site-list">
        <li><span>API 1: </span><span id="api-1">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 2: </span><span id="api-2">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 3: </span><span id="api-3">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 4: </span><span id="api-4">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 5: </span><span id="api-5">Loading...</span></li>
</ul>
    
<span>Total: </span><span id="count-total">Loading...</span>
```

Welp, still no luck.

Comment: **Thank you** for providing an actual runnable example of the problem! That's really great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I would like the total value to update only after `$.each` has finished iterating through the `url` variable.

Well, it does. :-) It's just that `$.each` doesn't wait for the asynchronous processes it starts to finish.

If you want all of those running at once, use `map` to gather the promises and `Promise.all` to wait for them all to be fulfilled (or for one of them to be rejected):

```js
function checkAll() {
    return Promise.all(Object.entries(url).map(([key, value]) =>
        fetchJSONList(value)
            .then(list => {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(0);
                }
                $.each(list, function() {
                    count[key]++;
                    count.total++;

                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(count[key]);
                });
            })
    ));
}
```

You also need to fix your call to `then` here:

```js
.then($("#count-total").text(count.total))
```

That **calls** `$(/*...*/).text(/*...*/)` and passes the return value into `then`. You want to pass `then` a function:

```js
.then(() => $("#count-total").text(count.total))
```

Also, there's no reason for `new Promise` in `fetchJSONList`; you *already* have a promise, just chain from it. But you do need to deal with the [`fetch` API footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) that it doesn't reject on HTTP error (just network error):

```js
function fetchJSONList(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

Putting that all together:

```js
let count = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    total: 0
};

let url = {
    1: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    2: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
    3: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    4: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
    5: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
};

function fetchJSONList(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}

function checkAll() {
    return Promise.all(Object.entries(url).map(([key, value]) =>
        fetchJSONList(value)
            .then(list => {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(0);
                }
                $.each(list, function() {
                    count[key]++;
                    count.total++;

                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(count[key]);
                });
            })
    ));
}

checkAll()
.then(() => $("#count-total").text(count.total))
.catch(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="site-list">
        <li><span>API 1: </span><span id="api-1">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 2: </span><span id="api-2">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 3: </span><span id="api-3">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 4: </span><span id="api-4">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 5: </span><span id="api-5">Loading...</span></li>
</ul>
    
<span>Total: </span><span id="count-total">Loading...</span>
```

If you want to wait for each of them to finish before starting the next one, build a promise chain with a loop:

```js
function checkAll() {
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(url)) {
        p = p.then(() => fetchJSONList(value))
            .then(list => {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(0);
                }
                $.each(list, function() {
                    count[key]++;
                    count.total++;

                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(count[key]);
                });
            });
    }
    return p;
}
```

```js
let count = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    total: 0
};

let url = {
    1: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    2: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
    3: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    4: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
    5: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
};

function fetchJSONList(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}

function checkAll() {
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(url)) {
        p = p.then(() => fetchJSONList(value))
            .then(list => {
                if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(0);
                }
                $.each(list, function() {
                    count[key]++;
                    count.total++;

                    const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                    $(spanID).text(count[key]);
                });
            });
    }
    return p;
}

checkAll()
.then(() => $("#count-total").text(count.total))
.catch(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="site-list">
        <li><span>API 1: </span><span id="api-1">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 2: </span><span id="api-2">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 3: </span><span id="api-3">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 4: </span><span id="api-4">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 5: </span><span id="api-5">Loading...</span></li>
</ul>
    
<span>Total: </span><span id="count-total">Loading...</span>
```

Or if your environment supports them, use an `async` function:

```js
async function checkAll() {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(url)) {
        const list = await fetchJSONList(value);
        if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
            const spanID = "#api-" + key;
            $(spanID).text(0);
        }
        $.each(list, function() {
            count[key]++;
            count.total++;

            const spanID = "#api-" + key;
            $(spanID).text(count[key]);
        });
    }
}
```

```js
let count = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    total: 0
};

let url = {
    1: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    2: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
    3: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    4: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
    5: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
};

function fetchJSONList(url) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}

async function checkAll() {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(url)) {
        const list = await fetchJSONList(value);
        if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
            const spanID = "#api-" + key;
            $(spanID).text(0);
        }
        $.each(list, function() {
            count[key]++;
            count.total++;

            const spanID = "#api-" + key;
            $(spanID).text(count[key]);
        });
    }
}

checkAll()
.then(() => $("#count-total").text(count.total))
.catch(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="site-list">
        <li><span>API 1: </span><span id="api-1">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 2: </span><span id="api-2">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 3: </span><span id="api-3">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 4: </span><span id="api-4">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 5: </span><span id="api-5">Loading...</span></li>
</ul>
    
<span>Total: </span><span id="count-total">Loading...</span>
```

Comment: I totally didn't think of the vanilla `map` XD Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait a second... For the execution of `checkAll()` below, is it still using `.then()` to update the value?

Comment: @frankly.not.frank - Yes, in both of the first two code blocks above. In the third code block it uses the `async` function equivalent of `then` (putting the code after an `await`).

Comment: Hmm, what is wrong with my second version though… I figured that `checkAll()` was kind of redundant in that way, so I moved the code outside.

Comment: @frankly.not.frank - Sorry, I missed that there was a problem with the way you were using `then`. I've updated the answer (and added live snippets -- I don't know why I didn't do that initially, I guess I'm used to people using snippets that don't run and I didn't even check).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let count = {
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    total: 0
};

let url = {
    1: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    2: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
    3: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",
    4: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
    5: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
};

function fetchJSONList(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => { return response.json(); })
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
    });
}

function checkAll() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.each(url, function(key) {
            fetchJSONList(url[key])
                .then(list => {
                    if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
                        const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                        $(spanID).text(0);
                    }
                    $.each(list, function() {
                        count[key]++;
                        count.total++;

                        const spanID = "#api-" + key;
                        $(spanID).text(count[key]);
                        $('#count-total').text(count.total);
                    });
                })
                .catch(reject);
        });
        resolve(count);
    });
}

checkAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="site-list">
        <li><span>API 1: </span><span id="api-1">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 2: </span><span id="api-2">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 3: </span><span id="api-3">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 4: </span><span id="api-4">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 5: </span><span id="api-5">Loading...</span></li>
</ul>
    
<span>Total: </span><span id="count-total">Loading...</span>
```

My idea is to just render the total directly in the loop. I moved your assignment for count-total inside the loop. and call only the function. Hopefully it works.

Comment: I tried that one, but the problem is that if all 5 APIs load at different times (e.g. due to connection issues), the total would be inaccurate until the slowest one is loaded. But thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: no worries. I think someone already provided better explanation about how to handle the promise :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

You resolved before any promises are fulfilled. So the solution is to use `Promise.all`

Below snippet could help you (I delayed one second before displaying total, so you could clearly see the behavior)

```js
let count = {
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 0,
  total: 0
}

let url = {
  1: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  2: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
  3: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
  4: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
  5: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
}

function fetchJSONList(key) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fetch(url[key])
      .then(response => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(list => resolve([key, list]))
      .catch(reject)
  })
}

function checkAll() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Promise.all(Object.keys(url).map(key => fetchJSONList(key)))
      .then(results => {
        results.forEach(([key, list = []]) => {
          if ($.isEmptyObject(list)) {
            const spanID = '#api-' + key
            $(spanID).text(0)
          }
          $.each(list, function() {
            count[key]++
            count.total++

            const spanID = '#api-' + key
            $(spanID).text(count[key])
          })
        })
        
        setTimeout(() => {
          $('#count-total').text(count.total)
          resolve()
        }, 1000)
      })
      .catch(reject)
  })
}

checkAll()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="site-list">
        <li><span>API 1: </span><span id="api-1">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 2: </span><span id="api-2">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 3: </span><span id="api-3">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 4: </span><span id="api-4">Loading...</span></li>
        <li><span>API 5: </span><span id="api-5">Loading...</span></li>
</ul>
    
<span>Total: </span><span id="count-total">Loading...</span>
```